# Two questions about Racket macro

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

1. About hygienic macro

   I don't fully understand how hygienic macro work. Here is two example.
   first one is:

```
    #lang racket
    (define-syntax (g stx)
      (syntax-case stx ()
        ([_ arg]
         #'(display arg))))

    (let ([display 1])
      (g 3))
```

this works fine but this one:

```
    #lang racket
    (define-syntax (g stx)
      (syntax-case stx ()
        ([_ arg]
         #'(display arg))))

    (define display 1)

    (g 3)
```

will raise an exception. How to explain the difference between the two case?

2. How to define a macro like this

   I want to define a macro to allow anonymous recursive function in racket.
   This one won't work because recur is not defined in the module:

```
    #lang racket
    (define Z
      (λ(recur)
        ((λ(x) (recur (λ(y) (x x) y)))
         (λ(x) (recur (λ(y) (x x) y))))))

    (define-syntax-rule (R proc)
      (Z (λ(recur) proc)))

    ((R (λ(n)
          (if [= n 1]
              1
              (* n (recur (- n 1)))))) 3)
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: This question would be better if it were split into its two separate questions and each stood on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to break hygene? You need to get `recur` to have the lexical context of the original form such that `recur` will be seen as the same identifier. You can do this with `datum->syntax` and the result might look something like this:

```scm
(define-syntax (recur-λ stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ args body ...)
     (with-syntax ([recur-stx (datum->syntax stx 'recur)])
       #'(Z (λ (recur-stx)
              (λ args body ...))))]))
```

Now as long as your args or the nesting in body introduces `recur` it will work:

```scm
; multiple argument recursion
(define Z
  (λ (f)
    ((λ (g) (g g))
     (λ (g)
       (f (λ args (apply (g g) args)))))))


; ackerman    
((recur-λ (m n)
     (cond
       ((= m 0) (+ n 1))
       ((= n 0) (recur (- m 1) 1))
       (else (recur (- m 1) (recur m (- n 1))))))
 3
 6)
; ==> 509
```

It won't work if you make `recur` an argument:

```scm
((recur-λ (recur) (recur 1)) 1)
; ==> error: recur not a procedure
```

And of course if you make a nested binding:

```scm
((recur-λ (a) 
   (define recur a) 
   (recur 1))
 1)
; ==> error: recur not a procedure
```

And of course you can step through the macroexpander and it will show you that it does something like this:

```scm
(expand-once 
 #'(recur-λ (m n)
     (cond
       ((= m 0) (+ n 1))
       ((= n 0) (recur (- m 1) 1))
       (else (recur (- m 1) (recur m (- n 1)))))))

; ==>
; #'(Z
;    (λ (recur)
;      (λ (m n)
;        (cond
;         ((= m 0) (+ n 1))
;         ((= n 0) (recur (- m 1) 1))
;         (else (recur (- m 1) (recur m (- n 1))))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question, the thing your forgetting here is that when you do a module level `define` like that, that definition is bound for the whole module. So, you could, theoretically write your second code block like this:

```
#lang racket
(let ([display 1])
  (define-syntax (g stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      ([_ arg]
       #'(display arg))))

  (g 3))
```

And now it makes sense why you get an error, because the display in your macro is bound to `1`, which is not a function.

Long story short, think of hygiene just as lexical scope. Whatever `display` is bound to when you *define* your macro is what it will be. (This is opposed to macros in other languages, where whatever `display` is bound to when you *call* (or really *expand*) the macro, is what it will be.

Now, to answer your second question, I apologize, but am unclear what you are trying to ask here. If you could clean it up a bit  then I can fill in this part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps a lot. And as Sylwester said what I really want to do is to break hygene here in the second question.